# Tags not rendering in the correct location

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

I have tags after body in article but its not rendering in the correct place.
Instead it displays at the end.

I have included the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Probably a css issue?

Comment: are you using tpl for the node?

Comment: no its a standard page.

Comment: Please provide more information, as it is, there is little chance to know why this happens. You could tell us if you're using any template tool like e.g. panels or just post the markup of that page to see if it's ordered correctly.

Comment: Its just a vanilla drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, try rearranging the fields then save. after that rearrange again to the original order of fields, save then clear all caches.